# Test order Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting issue?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have some test code that seems to be running out of the correct order.

```
[TestClass]
public class DirTest {
  public DirTest() {
    Assert.AreEqual( Directory.Exists( "testpath" ), true );
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestMethod1() {
  }

  [ClassInitialize]
  public static void InitTest( TestContext context ) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory( "testpath" );
  }
}
```

It throws an error that the directory does not exist, shouldn't ClassInitialize run before the class constructor is called or is there something I need to do that is missing. If that is not the case is there a test case other then AssemblyInitialize that can be included in the test that is called prior to the class being constructed?

-- Edit
The real issue is here, the top is a simplification.

```
//RealClass.cs
public class RealClass{
  public RealClass( string path ){
    this._path = path;
    this._InitDirectory();
  }

  protected string _path;
  protected void _InitDirectory(){
    //Something that requires read from path
    File.WriteAllText( this._path + "/realData.data", "some real data that needs to be created by the class" );
  }
}

//DirTest.cs
[TestClass]
public class DirTest : RealClass {
  public DirTest() : base( "testpath" ) {}

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestMethod1() {
  }

  [ClassInitialize]
  public static void InitTest( TestContext context ) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory( "testpath" );
  }
}
```

The unit test will fail because the directory where the path is required will die before the "ClassInitialize" method is called to create the mock directory required.

-- Edit

I have come up with a work around for this, though I would still like to know if there is another way to achieve the desired result without adding more classes, and without removing the functionality of the test. I have setup a "AssemblyInitialize" to a class that just contains that static method, and told that method to fire the static methods for "ClassInitialize". It of course fires before any constructors. Though the root of the issue is still unresolved as it is not self contained but dependent on a class function to call the class setup.

Comment: Do you really have relative path or just show it for sample? (Indeed creating folders is bad idea for unit tests, but it is not part of this question).

Comment: Constructors are executed first in always.

Comment: The idea was to show in a simple way that if I were to test a class with inheritance that needs something before the class is constructed it would fail to create the class. If your class needs folders for a test then NO it is not a bad idea to test creating and destroying them for the test, how else would you be able to share your test? I understand that when a class is creating the Constructors are always called first, but this is a static method. Why would it be static if the idea was to require the construction of the class?

Comment: As @GlennFerrieLive mentioned, the class constructor is executed first. Just because the `InitTest` method is static doesn't mean that it should automatically be executed before the `DirTest` constructor. MSTest is free to call it whenever it likes - the only guarantee that it provides is that the `[ClassInitialize]` function will be executed before any `[TestMethod]` functions are executed.

Comment: @Lilshieste so is there another method that is called other then "AssemblyInitialize" which can only be added to the test assembly once that will be called before the class is constructed, to do a proper test setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the approach of deriving your `[TestClass]` from your SUT class in order to access protected methods.

Firstly: is what you're doing really necessary? In the code you posted, there are no tests that explicitly try to access a protected member of the SUT. So, it's possible that you're making things more difficult than they need to be.

Now, if you *do* actually need to test a protected member in this SUT class, then have you considered creating an class that inherits from the SUT class - a class that isn't the `[TestClass]`? For example:

```
//RealClass.cs
public class RealClass{
    public RealClass( string path ){
        this._path = path;
        this._InitDirectory();
    }

    protected string _path;
    protected void _InitDirectory(){
        //Something that requires read from path
        File.WriteAllText( this._path + "/realData.data", "some real data that needs to be created by the class" );
   }
}

// TestableRealClass.cs - Only used by the unit test
public class TestableRealClass: RealClass {
    public TestableRealClass(string path) : base(path) { }        

    public string Path {
        get {
            return _path;
        }
    }

    public InitDirectory() {
        _InitDirectory();
    }
}

//DirTest.cs
[TestClass]
public class DirTest {

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() {
        var testPath = @"C:\SomePath";

        if (!Directory.Exists( testPath )) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory( testPath );
        }

        var sut = new TestableRealClass(testPath);

        AssertThatTheFileContainsExpectedStuff(testPath);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAProtectedMember() {
        var testPath = @"C:\SomePath";

        if (!Directory.Exists( testPath )) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory( testPath );
        }

        var sut = new TestableRealClass(testPath);

        Assert.AreEqual(testPath, sut.Path);
    }

    private void AssertThatTheFileContainsExpectedStuff(string path) {
        // Do the assertion...
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about the order in which the text fixture will initialize, and your tests become considerably easier to understand.

Comment: The example I provided was meant to be rather small, yes it is necessary to test the class prior to inheriting. You are correct there are no test, but I am trying to get to the point without giving an overwhelming amount of code. I see your logic however I do not see it making "tests become considerably easier to understand." I see it having me write 2 classes rather then one.

Comment: You remember how you were confused about the order in which the constructor and the static method would be executed? Readers of your test would be greeted with the same confusion, making your tests harder to understand. As for writing two classes instead of one: you're absolutely right; there is an extra class. On the other hand, this approach has the added benefit of actually working.

Comment: The work around seems to work well. While it is not totally self contained it is by no means messy, and forces the execution order to be more logical. I think logically it is easier to understand that a static ClassInitialize method would be called prior to the class being initialized if the cleanup is called after the class is destroyed(which it is).

Comment: I agree that there are other, more logical ways that the whole setup/teardown process could have been designed. IMO, it's a bit more straightforward in other testing frameworks, like gtest.

Answer (score 0):

update your code as follows:

```
[TestClass]
public class DirTest {
  public DirTest() { }

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestMethod1() {
  }

  [ClassInitialize]
  public static void InitTest( TestContext context ) {
            if (!Directory.Exists( "testpath" )) {
                Directory.CreateDirectory( "testpath" );
            }
  }
}
```

Comment: Assert.AreEqual( Directory.Exists( "testpath" ), true ); is the very point of the test. Your missing the point of this issue.

Comment: @Stev0 you should've have a test in the constructor of the Test harness.  It should be in a TestMethod in that case.

Comment: I put the test in the constructor to show the order issue, that would rise from doing a test using a inherited base class. Again missing the point.

Comment: @Stev0 I think you're fundamentally misusing Unit Tests.  You shouldn't have an Assert in the constructor.  All Asserts should be in TestMethods and Initialize is to prepare for tests.  If you want to do ordered unit tests (which are a real thing) you do it as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182630(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I have made some edits based on your comment that I am "fundamentally misusing Unit Tests," so tell me, how would you test the RealClass correctly? Don't tell me that I shouldn't use inheritance, because without it there is no way that I know of to test protected methods, and therefor testing to make sure the base class operates as intended for the other classes that inherit it.